OpenAI Connection Error when running Python Langchain on GCS
I've deployed a flask application to Google Cloud Services. When I run Langchain's similarity_search_with_relevance_scores on my document/database set, it throws a vaugue openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error.
Which is strange because locally, it works. Here's my code:
def query_gpt(query, version):
    print(f"recieved {query}")
    query_text = query
    embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=api_key)
    print("created embedding_function")
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH, embedding_function=embedding_function)
    print(f"created db: {db}")
    # Search the DB
    results = db.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores(query_text, k=5) 
    # ----- openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error ------
    print(f"results: {results}")

Can anyone provide more insight into this? No one else seems to be having this issue.
(Stacktrace is pretty long so I had to screenshot it, attached)




Can you provide the full error you get along with APIConnectionError?

Sachin Hosmani Done
